# MySql gives an error for no reason at all?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am writing an mysql program (using the command line editor):

```
CREATE TABLE FLIGHTS (
FL_NO  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
STARTING VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
ENDING VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
NO_FLIGTHS INT NOT NULL,
NO_STOPS INT NOT NULL
);
```

this is somehow gives an error which is surprising. any idea?

> Error message:
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'STARTING VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
> ENDING VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
> NO_FLIGHTS INTEGER N' at line 3

Comment: would you mind to share with us the exact error?

Comment: I did add it tysm for the suggestion :D

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: MySQL's error 1064 shows you the part of the SQL statement coming immediiately *after* the part it can't understand. So backing up from `STARTING VARCH...` you ge the first line of the table definition.

Answer (score -1):

`STARTING` and `ENDING` are keywords, and MySql does not accept keywords as column names, changing them should help...

Comment: This is not entirely true.

Comment: MySql does not accept RESERVED as column names, -Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them as described in Section 9.2, “Schema Object Names”: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-S